# jQuery.draggable restore styles after cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, cancellation

I am stopping jQuery.draggable on a specific condition. This works well, but I realized that the styles of my dragged object that are defined within my call of draggable()

```
 $target.draggable({
    cursor: 'no-drop',
    zIndex: 1000,
    opacity: 0.7,
```

are not restored.
The only solution I found was to remove all css attributes. Thus, my code looks like:

```
function initDrag($target) {
$target.draggable({
    cursor: 'no-drop',
    zIndex: 1000,
    opacity: 0.7,

    start: function (event, ui) {
        if (!myDragCondition()) {
            $('body').css('cursor', '');
            $target.css('z-index', '');
            $target.css('opacity', '');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            /*
            * Some more code...
            */
            return true;
        }

    },
    revert: 'invalid',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        /*
        * My code here...
        */
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        /*
        * My code here...
        */
    }
});
}
```

But I am not very happy with my solution because it depends very much on the fact how jQuery implements its style changes. Is there a better way?